# Illegal XML character: 0x10 in Oracle Service Bus

Tags: xml, oracle, weblogic, cdata, osb

I am using Oracle OSB and Weblogic 12c. XML version is 1.0.

I have an interface that can recieve incoming requests from backend party. Everytime when the backend party sends a request message, the message jumps in to the error queue and the proxy service throws and error with message:

`Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA ................Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Illegal XML character: 0x10`

I can't seem to pinpoint where the illegal character is located. When I open the pipeline with Notepad ++ I can see some xquery CDATA lines that looks like this:

```
<![CDATA[<ns0:Request xmlns="" xmlns:ns0="http://blabla/testest">
           <ns0:MessageType>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:MessageType/text() }</ns0:MessageType>
           <ns0:Feature>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:Feature/text() }</ns0:Feature>
           <ns0:Identity>
               <ns0:nummer>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:Identity/ns0:nummer/text() }</ns0:nummer>
               <ns0:type>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:Identity/ns0:type/text() }</ns0:type>
           </ns0:Identity>
           <ns0:InterestedParty>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:InterestedParty/text() }</ns0:InterestedParty>
           <ns0:ReceiveParty>
               <ns0:nummer>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:ReceiveParty/ns0:nummer/text() }</ns0:nummer>
               <ns0:type>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:ReceiveParty/ns0:type/text() }</ns0:type>
           </ns0:ReceiveParty>
           <ns0:PartyRole>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:PartyRole/text() }</ns0:PartyRole>
           <ns0:SubjectMessage>
               <ns0:mimeType>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:SubjectMessage/ns0:mimeType/text() }</ns0:mimeType>
               <ns0:Filename>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:SubjectMessage/ns0:Filename/text() }</ns0:Filename>
               <ns0:subject>{ $body/ns0:Request/ns0:SubjectMessage/ns0:subject/text() }</ns0:subject>
           </ns0:SubjectMessage>
           <ns0:autorisatieAdres>http://geenausp.nl</ns0:autorisatieAdres>
       </ns0:Request>
```

If I test the message in the Service Bus Console, it works fine. This error only occurs when message is recieved from outside.

**What have I tried:**

I have tried to add a line in setDomainenv with the following java option:
-Dcom.bea.osb.http.cookieAsNoComplexElement=true

That didn't seem to work.

**Update**:
The initial request message has a base64 element. If the backend party sends the messsage without that line, the flow works fine. But the strange part is, if I test the same message inside the Service Bus console, it works fine! So where does it go wrong?

Comment: Open the data in a hex editor and see what the first character is. `0x10` is a "data link escape" character and may not be displayed in a text editor.

Comment: Here's my problem. When you mention 'data' I don't know which data this problem occurs. The request message doesn't contain any CDATA. When logging tells me that there is an illligal character, my question rises, where? Request message? Metadata? Pipeline actions?

Answer (score 0):

The request message was sent as MIME version 1.0 instead of XML version 1.0. I believe this is sent in the header by the request party. Pipeline raises error because of this, only accepts XML type.